# What is the correct scientific term of having a short-term or long-term mindset (in the field of health and healthy lifestyle)?

Tags: terminology

For research on changing lifestyle behaviours to prevent future disease, I am looking for literature on what the influence is of having a **short-term versus a long-term oriented mindset**. However, I cannot come up with the correct term for this and therefore do not manage to find useful scientific literature. 
Any suggestions? Perhaps even recommendations of literature?

Comment: Consideration of future consequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One search term that might be useful is **[temporal discounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_discounting)**.

Here's a relevant [Psychlopedia article](http://www.psych-it.com.au/Psychlopedia/article.asp?id=427), and a [relatively recent paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24799134) that may have some useful references for navigating the literature.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Josh' answer, I eventually ended up with 'delay gratification' and planning to use the Delay Gratification Inventory to measure this in participants.

Hoerger M, Quirk SW, Weed NC. Development and validation of the Delaying Gratification Inventory. Psychological assessment. 2011;23(3):725-738. doi:10.1037/a0023286.